# Google Sheet multiple matches in uneven data structure

Tags: google-sheets, google-sheets-formula

I got this "table" (page raids) and want to do function formatting for highlight duplicates (yellow).

[Google Sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1elELn0c34MXNo_SEfQk66YEePuvL1uorDThJSQ-nYBg/edit?usp=sharing)

In this case there is match in 2 strings (dark blue):

```
Name1
Gunslinger
```

[image: ss 1]

I already tried functions `VLOOKUP`, Match, Filter, countifs and query (don't know how it works...) with index function, but nothing seems work as I want ...

`VLOOKUP` and `Match` only return the first value.

Filter doesn't work on this stuck or I don't know how to use it in this case (I know how it works in normal table).

Can someone tell me what function combination to use that can be put in function formatting?

Formatting for each row:

Example:

```
=IF(B3>0;IF(B4<1490;TRUE;FALSE);FALSE)
```

[image: ss 2]

[image: ss 3]

etc.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After some searching and testing, I came up with this:

```
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(FIND(B2&B3;MID(CONCATENATE((TRANSPOSE($B$2:$I$33)));SEQUENCE(LEN(CONCATENATE((TRANSPOSE($B$2:$I$33))));1;1;1);len(B2&B3)))=1)*1))>1
```

Still need to make the functions more tidy (picture 2 and 3).

Answer (score 0):

See if this is what you are looking for?

[image]

Conditional formatting with Custom formula in `Range: A2:H`:

```
=LAMBDA(NAME,OR(A1=NAME,A2=NAME,A3=NAME))("Gunslinger")
```

or do you means you want to highlight only duplicates?

If that is the case, you may try this formula:

[image: image2]

```
=LAMBDA(DATARANGE,
 LAMBDA(FLAT,
  {{"Team","Duplicate"};{UNIQUE(FLAT),BYROW(UNIQUE(FLAT),LAMBDA(NAME,COUNTIF(FLAT,NAME)>1))}}
 )(
  QUERY(FLATTEN(
   BYCOL(DATARANGE,LAMBDA(C,
    BYROW(C,LAMBDA(R,
     IF((ROW(R)+1)/4=INT((ROW(R)+1)/4),R,"")
    ))
   ))
  ),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",0)
 )
)(A2:H)
```

This formula returns an array of unique Names with checking if there are Duplicates in the given datarange.

Combine this with the 1st formula should be able to highlight repeated data sets from your table.

---

Solution for 2 criteria matching:

[image: image3]

The formula inside the image form the table of unique match results,
use that result with `OR()`, `XLOOKUP()`, `OFFSET()`, `INDEX()` as below for the final formula to put into the custom formula in conditional formatting.

```
=LAMBDA(RESULT,
 LAMBDA(NAME,DUP,KEY,
  LAMBDA(KEY_M2,KEY_M1,KEY_P1,
   OR(
    XLOOKUP(KEY_M2&"&&"&KEY_M1,NAME,DUP,FALSE),
    XLOOKUP(KEY_M1&"&&"&KEY,NAME,DUP,FALSE),
    XLOOKUP(KEY&"&&"&KEY_P1,NAME,DUP,FALSE)
   )
  )(IFERROR(OFFSET(KEY,-2,0),""),IFERROR(OFFSET(KEY,-1,0),""),IFERROR(OFFSET(KEY,1,0),""))
 )(INDEX(RESULT,,1),INDEX(RESULT,,2),A2)
)(
 LAMBDA(DATARANGE,
  LAMBDA(FLATCLASS,
   {{"Name","Duplicate"};{UNIQUE(FLATCLASS),BYROW(UNIQUE(FLATCLASS),LAMBDA(NAME,COUNTIF(FLATCLASS,NAME)>1))}}
  )(
   QUERY(FLATTEN(
    BYCOL(DATARANGE,LAMBDA(C,
     BYROW(C,LAMBDA(R,
      IF((ROW(R)+1)/4=INT((ROW(R)+1)/4),IF(R="","",INDEX(C,ROW(R)-2)&"&&"&R),"")
     ))
    ))
   ),"SELECT Col1 WHERE Col1 IS NOT NULL",0)
  )
 )($A$2:$H)
)
```

Comment: Unfortunately no.
It has to take the first string (A2) also as criteria.
And the function needs to work with each range group (I edit the main post for more clarity)
Also I dont care if its only for one cell at time will just copy paste it multiple times If there isnt other way.

Comment: Was now trying to use Arrayformula with If statments with looked promising, but still have problem with the 2 string criteria...

Comment: you mean it should only returns true if both the "Name" and the "Class" thing matches?

Comment: updated the formula to match for 2 string

Comment: this formula in conditional formatting take quite some time to load, so if your spreadsheet is too long, you may get a timeout error.

Comment: So you're solution works, but as you said it takes too much time ... and my data validetion that leads to functions doesnt work ...
So I did some more reaserch and thought I would just creat big string and search in it.
=ArrayFormula(SUM(IFERROR(FIND(B2&B3;MID(CONCATENATE((TRANSPOSE(B2:I33)));SEQUENCE(LEN(CONCATENATE((TRANSPOSE(B2:I33))));1;1;1);50))=1)*1))>1
With works, but it also hightligh some empty spaces and only works on first duplicate.

Comment: Also I rly like how you used lamba for multiple cells as of now I use Function formating for each row ... I added pictures into main post

Comment: just be remined that you do have a upper limite of 50,000 char length for one string in google sheet as I can remember.